# Easy Audio Cutter for Ubuntu

Tags: sound

Are there any Easy Audio Cutter??? Like [this?](http://www.koyotesoft.com/audio-software/easy-mp3-ogg-wma-cutter.html) For Ubuntu?

Or is possible use this program with Wine?

Comment: You can use the [online mp3 cutter tools](http://www.akshatblog.com/mp3-cutter/) which are very easy to use and does requires installation on your computer. I have used them and they work great. Just upload your audio file using your browsers, set markers and then clip the audio file and save it to your hard disk.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. Try [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), which is a cross-platform easy-to-use piece of software for multitrack audio editing, which will allow you to do what Easy Audio Cutter does and a lot of additional tasks.

Screenshot from the official website:

[image]

To install it you can simply hit the Software Center and run a search for Audacity, or in a terminal drop the next command line:

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Provide your user password and wait for the software to finish installing. Then run it via your favorite launcher or in a terminal write `audacity` and press enter.

Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

you can use VLC media player also. After opening click at View option and enable advanced tab. then you will see red button  and click it to start recording and click to stop. In between on/off what ever has played will be recorded and saved.

[image]